# SQL Server 2008 Union Select 'creating' non-existent records

Tags: sql-server

The results of a union select statement in SQL Server 2008 is including records that are not found in either source table.  Example:

theid is an integer ID value within each source table.  Neither table includes theid value of 277741.

```
Select *
From DataTable1
WHere theid = 277741
-- 0 records returned

Select *
From DataTable2
Where theid = 277741
-- 0 records returned
```

However, when you run the Union Select statement below, a record is generated for theid.

```
Select *
Into ConjoinedData
From DataTable1
Union
Select *
From DataTable2
Where theid Not In (Select theid From DataTable1)

Select 
From ConjoinedData
Where theid = 27741
-- 1 record returned
```

The theid field is not an identity field in either source table.  Ultimately, the data for DataTable1 and DataTable2 came from the same parent, whose content includes an unrelated record with ID 277741.  However, there are no foreign key relationships to it or any other table on either of the source tables.  I have tried changing to a Union All query with no success.  I have created an index on theid in both source tables and the 'created' record appears.  I have dropped and recreated the source tables numerous times to no avail.  Why is SQL Server getting the unrelated record from the disconnected parent table (source talbes were both cereated from the same parent using Select..Into statements and no foreign key relationship to either table back to the parent)?

Comment: Please provide a repro script demonstrating your issue.

Comment: What is missing from the script already provided that you need?

Comment: Note that UNION removes duplicates, so your query

    Select *
    Into ConjoinedData
    From DataTable1
    Union
    Select *
    From DataTable2
    Where theid Not In (Select theid From DataTable1)

should be just

    Select *
    Into ConjoinedData
    From DataTable1
    Union
    Select *
    From DataTable2

is "theid" unique? is it an int?

Answer (score 1):

`277741` is different from `27741`.  The following script reproduces exactly what you describe:

```
create table Table1 (id int);
create table Table2 (id int);
go

insert into Table1(id) values (277742);
insert into Table2(id) values (27741);
go


Select * From Table1 WHere id = 277741;
Select * From Table2 Where id = 277741;
go

Select *
Into ConjoinedData
From Table1
Union
Select *
From Table2
Where id Not In (Select id From Table1);

Select *
From ConjoinedData
Where id = 27741;
```

Comment: THe value 27741 is a typo.  Ther ID coming back in teh 'created' record is 277741.  Note that the record exists in the parent, but is not part of either child and the union is intended to join only the child tables.  The result of that join is still a subset of the parent.

Comment: Then fix your question. Also, provide the *exact* table definition.